# how do we do enum constructor in objective c

Tags: objective-c, enums, nsenumerator

In java we can easily do the following enum

```
public enum Food {
    HAMBURGER(7), FRIES(2), HOTDOG(3), ARTICHOKE(4);

    Food(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    private final int price;

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

[Source](https://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-the-enum-type-with-a-constructor.html)

But I would like to do the same enum but as far as I read I couldn't find any way to do constructor in objective C like we do in java.

How to achieve the same in objective c ?

Comment: Objective-C (a superset of C) enums don't support such abilities. Swift does though.

Answer (score 3):

(Objective-)C enumerations are *very* basic.

They are not the type defined by a collection of literals, e.g. as in Ada or Pascal, though they might appear to be; neither are they the tagged disjoint union, e.g. as in Swift or Java.

Instead they are simply a collection of constants, usually of `int` type though this can be changed to other integral types, which can be used more-or-less interchangeably as an `int` (or whatever integral type the are).

However, if your enumeration is just as described above then you can achieve something similar with a C style enum:

```
typedef enum
{
   HAMBURGER = 7,
   FRIES = 2,
   HOTDOG = 3,
   ARTICHOKE = 4
} Food;
```

This gives you a type, `Food`, with four literal values, `HAMBURGER` *et al*; and assignment, equality, `switch` statements etc. all work as expected. E.g.:

```
Food item = HOTDOG;
if (item == FRIES) ...
switch (item) { case ARTICHOKE: ...
```

You can also use the literals as integers to get the "price", e.g.

```
int itemPrice = (int)item;
```

Multiple literals can be given the same value in the underlying type, so you can have different items with the same price.

Given this you *might* be able to achieve something similar to your Java code without any coding beyond declaring the `enum`. However if you are using the full capabilities of Java enumerations you will have to define your own `class`/`struct` and methods/functions to implement the functionality you require.

HTH